# Question regarding a confusing sentence:

Tags: meaning, grammar, commas

> The truth is, we are all affected by the people we interact with, many of whom we don't even know personally

In the above sentence, what is it that 'we' don't know? 'Those people' or 'this truth'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The statement refers to the people we interact with. Don't be misled by the comma after "The truth is" ... think of it as a substitute for the word "that" in this case.

> The truth is [that] we are all affected by the people we interact with, many of whom we don't even know personally.

This construction is seen in similar statements, like

> The fact is, I don't have any money.
>
> The crux of the matter is, you won the lottery and I didn't.

It's kind of a loophole in what you would think of as normal usage for the comma, but it is in wide circulation. The fact of the matter is, pretty much everyone uses it that way.

Comment: To this, I would like to add that *we know many of this truth personally* would be ungrammatical. *Truth* is uncountable, so you'd use *much* with it. Thus, it can only be *we know many of those people personally*.

Comment: Sorry. I still cannot understand. Could you split the sentence to two ?  the first is what's the truth? and the other, what we don't know ? thank you!

Comment: "The truth is this:  We are all affected by the *people* we interact with, many of [these *people*] we don't even know."

Comment: we don't even know those people ? I see !

Answer (score 0):

Because it says "many of whom" we know that the writer is referring to people. Whom is a pronoun.

Answer (score -2):

This is one of those times when proper grammar is your friend.

If you rewrite the sentence correctly, look how easy it becomes:

> The truth is, we are all affected by
>   the people *with whom* we interact,
>   many *of whom* we don't even know personally.

Comment: This does not answer the OP's question, it merely invites the OP to attempt to parse a new structure in order to deduce the answer for themselves.